# Transferring encrypted data using Sqoop

Tags: encryption, sqoop

Is this use case possible:

To first extract data, encrypt it, transfer it over the network, decrypt it and load in hive or HDFS using Sqoop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by following below steps :

1. Use sqoop codegen tool to generate mapper code which handles deserialization of table data.
2. Modify this code to encrypt the data read from table. Each instance represents one row.
3. Now run sqoop import command which will use this modified mapper code to generate encrypted data. This is transmitted to hdfs.
4. Use decryption logic over output files in hdfs to get back the content.

Comment: thanks...but then I have another query, this encryption where it will happen..at source or Target...i want data to be travel secure

Comment: It's something like this : mapper will establish connection with database -> read data from database -> encrypt -> write encrypted data as mapper output which is what travells on the network to target. Data between mapper machines and your database server would be already secure using jdbc connection or you can use ssl here.